# Composite foreign key properties Conflict when running testing

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, data-annotations

I am working with c#, .net5, and I have successfully included two new Entities (tables `TableA` and `TableB`) to my already working solution. The solution run smoothly, even though adding new entries to the new two tables runs without problem.

The issue comes when I try to run a very simple new Testing class (IClassFixture). when I run a basic method test, I have this following error,

> System.AggregateException : The relationship from `'EntityB.FK'` to `'EntityA'` with foreign key
> properties `{'MTime' : DateTime, 'MId' : long}` cannot target the
> primary key `{'Id' : long}` because it is not compatible. Configure a
> principal key or a set of compatible foreign key properties for this
> relationship.

so I don't understand why and how such an error comes here (even though the system is running without any issue) ? is there any solution to bypass this ?

```
public class EntityA
{

        [Key]
        [Column("id")]
        public long Id { get; set; }

        [Column("time")]
        [Required]
        public DateTime Time { get; set; }

        [Column("value")]
        [Required]
        public float Value { get; set; }

}
```

```
 public class EntityB
{

        [Key]
        [Column("id")]
        public long Id { get; set; }

        [Column("value", TypeName = "jsonb")]
        [Required]
        public string Value { get; set; }

        [Column("m_id")]
        [Required]
        public long MId { get; set; }

        [Column("m_time")]
        public DateTime MTime { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("MTime, MId")]
        public virtual EntityA FK{ get; set; }

}
```

Note that the `EntityA` has two primary keys and are added successfully to the database.

```
                modelBuilder.Entity<EntityA>().HasKey(m =>
                    new { m.Time, m.Id });
```